# Robolectric 3.3.1 unit test issue

Tags: android

I was trying ribolectric version 3.3.2 unit test with mvp in android studio version 3.0. facing the below issues.
can any please help me out.

### Unable to resolve artifact: Missing:

1) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:7.1.0_r7-robolectric-0

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=7.1.0_r7-robolectric-0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=7.1.0_r7-robolectric-0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
    2) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:7.1.0_r7-robolectric-0

---

1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)

```
at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecuteResolution(DependenciesTask.java:268)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecute(DependenciesTask.java:168)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.execute(AbstractArtifactTask.java:751)
at org.robolectric.internal.dependency.MavenDependencyResolver.getLocalArtifactUrls(MavenDependencyResolver.java:51)
at org.robolectric.internal.dependency.MavenDependencyResolver.getLocalArtifactUrl(MavenDependencyResolver.java:68)
at org.robolectric.internal.dependency.CachedDependencyResolver.getLocalArtifactUrl(CachedDependencyResolver.java:42)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxFactory.getSdkEnvironment(SandboxFactory.java:36)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getSandbox(RobolectricTestRunner.java:263)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getSandbox(RobolectricTestRunner.java:53)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:176)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:109)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:36)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

### Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:

1) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:7.1.0_r7-robolectric-0

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=7.1.0_r7-robolectric-0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.robolectric -DartifactId=android-all -Dversion=7.1.0_r7-robolectric-0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency: 
    1) org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0
    2) org.robolectric:android-all:jar:7.1.0_r7-robolectric-0

---

1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact: 
  org.apache.maven:super-pom:pom:2.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  sonatype (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/)

```
at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:360)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecuteResolution(DependenciesTask.java:263)
... 28 more
```

Process finished with exit code -1